# Two Dimensional Array Declaration and Initialisation in Java

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

```
String[][] twoD3;
twoD3 = {{"1234", "5435", "2345"}, {"pebbles"}};
```

What is the problem with the above array initialization? Why am I getting compile error? The error is:

> Syntax error on token ; ,, expected.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Try this:
      
      String[][] twoD3 = null;
      twoD3 = {{"1234", "5435"} ,{"2345","pebbles"}};
Or:
      
     String[][] twoD3 = {{"1234", "5435"} ,{"2345","pebbles"}};

Comment: Syntax error on token ; ,, expected.  -That's what it says

Comment: Is this within a method, or directly within a class declaration? (I can't reproduce that error message.) Ideally, provide a [mcve].

Comment: I am trying to declare in one line and initialize in the next line. That's when I am getting into trouble.

Comment: @JonSkeet I simply pasted that into my main method and I got the error message.

Comment: @CM1: That still doesn't tell us whether it's within a method/constructor or not.

Comment: @Gendarme: Interesting - in a method I get "error: illegal start of expression" at the open brace. Different versions of javac, I guess.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oops. My bad. I thought you did not get any error at all. Nevermind what I wrote.

Comment: Okay, I guess the problem is not related. The problem might be missing parenthesis somewhere in the program

Comment: Well the code you've given is certainly broken, as per answers. It doesn't help that you haven't told us where the error is reported. Again, showing a [mcve] would really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with it being an array of arrays. You'll see the same error with this simpler code with a single array:

```
String[] array;
array = { "foo", "bar" };
```

You can't do that - an [*array initializer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) can only be used on its own within a declaration, e.g.

```
String[] array = { "foo", "bar" };
```

For a normal expression (on the right hand side of the assignment operator), you need an [*array creation expression*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1), using the `new` keyword and specifying the array type:

```
String[] array;
array = new String[] { "foo", "bar" };
```

Or for your precise example:

```
String[][] twoD3;
twoD3 = new String[][] {{"1234", "5435", "2345"}, {"pebbles"}};
```

(Or just assign the value at the point of declaration, of course.)

Comment: I am getting error with this one too:                       String[] array;
array = new String[] { "foo", "bar" };

Comment: @CM1: You shouldn't, assuming that's within a method. What exact error, and where?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
 Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

 at packageOne.ArrayGame.main(ArrayGame.java:33)

Comment: I was trying to do it as an instance variable. I was not trying to do it inside a method. Why is that a problem? @Jon Skeet - Please explain

Comment: @CM1: Well to start with, don't try to run code that doesn't compile. Next, my code doesn't have any ( so it can't be a problem there. Yet again, it's very hard to help with such incomplete information.

Comment: @CM1: That's a problem because you tried to put a statement (not a declaration) directly in a class declaration. That's not allowed.

Comment: Okay, I see that!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the array in the same command that you declared it. Who knows why this is, it was a design choice by the creators of java.

```
    String[][] twoD3 = {{"1234", "5435", "2345"}, {"pebbles"}};
```

If you must separate the declaration and initialization, you can explicitly initialize it using `new`

```
    String[][] twoD3;
    twoD3 = new String[][]{{"1234", "5435", "2345"}, {"pebbles"}};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
    String[][] twoD3;

    twoD3 = new String[][]{{"1234", "5435", "2345"}, {"pebbles", "asd", "asd"}};
```

You need to create a new instance.

Comment: `String[][] twoD3 = {{"1234", "5435", "2345"}, {"pebbles", "asd", "asd"}}` would also create a new instance...

Answer (score 1):

```
String[][] twoD3 = {{"1234", "5435", "2345"}, {"pebbles"}};
```

The above line is the way to define and initialize the 2d array.